# Emacs: move the cursor to the last character of a word

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to move the cursor to the last character of the word?

If there isn't, how to write some functions in .emacs to have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `(forward-word)` that is bounded to <kbd>M-f</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

`ESC f` will move you forward one word, is that close enough to what you need?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```el
(defun my-end-of-word ()
  "Move to the next 'last character' of a word."
  (interactive)
  (forward-char)
  (re-search-forward "\\w\\b" nil t)
  (goto-char (match-beginning 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, `forward-word` exists and moves point to the character after the next word. If that does it for you, you're done.

If you'd *actually* like to move point to the last character of the next word, you'll need to move it back afterwards, which means using `backward-char`. You can already do that using `M-f C-b`, but if you'd like a function you can bind to a single keystroke, use something like

```
(defun last-in-word ()
   (interactive)
   (forward-word) 
   (backward-char))
```

and then bind it to the desired key as normal.